# Cannot convert 'char' to 'string' error when using string.Split

Tags: c#

I keep getting an error for splitting the name variable, please explain how I can fix this error

```
public string name;

    public string idrecipe;
    
    private int idnumbers;

    void Start() 
    {
        string[] idArray = idrecipe.Split(idrecipe, char.Parse(","));
        idnumbers = idArray.Length;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you passing `idrecipe` to `Split`? You're already calling `Split` _on_ `idrecipe`, so I'm not sure what you expect this to do. And you can simply write `','` instead of `char.Parse(",")`.

Comment: I've removed the `[visual-studio]` tag because this isn't a question about the Visual Studio application, and I've removed the `[unity3d]` tag because this question isn't related to Unity.

Comment: In c#, single quotes denote `char`'s and double quotes denote `string`'s; i.e. `char c = 'x';` verses `string s = "x";`

Comment: For future reference, if you Google "How to use String.Split C#", the first result is a full page written by the folks over at Microsoft on how to use this method: [How to separate strings using String.Split in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split). The second result is the main [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split) for `String.Split` with, again, numerous examples.

Comment: @John I wan to split idrecipe into an array and this is a unity sciprt :/

Comment: _"this is a unity sciprt"_ - it may be a Unity script, but it is a pure C#/.NET question. You could remove this code from Unity and put it into a console application and you would have the exact same problem. With that in mind, Unity is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks for the help, I finally got the correct code, it was

string[] idArray = idrecipe.Split(',');

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idrecipe))
  string[] idArray = idrecipe.Split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is already answered let me explain **why** it works the way it does.

Split wants a **character** to be the divider.  "," is a **string** that is one character long.  ',' is a **character**--note the single quote vs double quote.